# Create view in multiple databases

Tags: sql-server, view

I have a SQL Server 2012. I have a view that is written and it works. I need to drop and create that view across several dozen databases.

I don't want to have to change the `USE` clause at the top for each database. Ideally I would like to have a list of databases in a comma delimited string and to run it and the query drops and recreates the view in each database in the list. I know this could be done using dynamic SQL where the view text is in an `nvarchar`, but it is a large view and even a `varchar` wouldn't suffice. It would need an `ntext` or `nvarchar(max)`.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Are all of your databases on the same server?

Comment: How many databases are you talking about here? I fear that the dynamic solution would be more effort than it is worth. It can certainly be done. Instead of a delimited list it would be better if you had the database names in a table. Maybe just leveraging sys.databases with a proper where predicate?

Comment: [This procedure](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/) I wrote to replace the undocumented, unsupported, and laughably broken `sp_MSforeachdb` procedure takes a comma-separated list of databases as an argument. You can pass your `CREATE VIEW` code into that.

Comment: It's for a Sage 300 system so could potentially be anything from 2 or 3 databases, to 30 or 40 databases. Yes, all databases will be on the same server